# Getting grub rescue on boot, but can get to grub via 'BIOS'

Tags: windows-8, grubrescue

I'm pretty rubbish when it comes to understanding partitions and the Ubuntu boot process.  I have recently tried using the boot-repair application to re-instate my dual boot menu after installing Ubuntu 12.04 next to Windows 8.  Unfortunately after doing this, I get grub rescue :(.

I have a log here that boot repair produced http://paste.ubuntu.com/6190172/.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 and if on startup I press F12, I can choose Ubuntu or Windows to boot from.  Choosing 'Ubuntu' gives me the multi-select that I would expect.  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I had to put my boot back into UEFI mode (I had turned it off to get the boot USB to run)